# Derivative with respect to any element of a matrix

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix

I try to evaluate 
$$ \frac{\partial s}{\partial A_{ab}} $$ 
where 
$$ s = \sum_{i} \sum_{j} A_{ij}$$

The result should be 1 regardless of $a$ and $b$. But the following code gives zero.

```
L = 3
A = SymbolicMatrix["A", {L, L}]
s = Sum[Sum[A[i, j], {j, 1, L}], {i, 1, L}]
D[s, A[a, b]]
```

Result is 0 because Mathematica doesn't know A[a, b] refers to an element of Matrix A.

How to fix this?

Thanks again.

---

Update:

When I try assumptions, they don't completely solve the problem.

```
$Assumptions = (a | b) \[Element] Integers && 1 <= a <= L && 
   1 <= b <= L;
s = Sum[A[i, j], {j, 1, L}, {i, 1, L}];
s // TeXForm
D[s, A[a, b]]
```

[image]

Still 0 when I don't assign anything to $L$

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the upper limit symbolic (meaning, **don't** assign a value to `L`), define assumptions that can be used by [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum), and avoid using your undefined `SymbolicMatrix` function:

```
(* the following Clear is just in case you give a value to L *)
Clear[L]
$Assumptions=(a|b) ∈ Integers && 1<=a<=L && 1<=b<=L;
s = Sum[A[i, j], {j, 1, L}, {i, 1, L}];
s //TeXForm
```

> $\sum _{j=1}^L \sum _{i=1}^L A(i,j)$

Then, using [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) will do what you want:

```
D[s, A[a, b]]
```

> 1

Comment: After I cut, paste, and run the 3 + 1 lines of code, I still get 0.

Comment: `L = 10;
$Assumptions = Element[a | b, Integers] && 
       1 <= a <= L && 1 <= b <= L; 
s = Sum[A[i, j], {j, 1, L}, {i, 1, L}]; 
D[s, {A[a, b]}]` gives 0 as result.

Comment: No... I was trying a dozen of things and the code still gives 0.

Comment: Try ClearAll["Global`*"] before evaluating the code in the answer.

Comment: still 0 after opening new notebook and use ClearAll["Global*"]

Comment: @Rzu Don't assign a value to `L`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Still 0 even if I don't assign a value to L. I add 2nd screen shot to question to show this. The warning is a bit strange. let me restart Mathematica and try again. I'm using Linux version.

Comment: It is finally 1 after I restart Mathematica. Very strange. Thanks for helping me.