# Simplify sum of Kronecker delta

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following simplification is correct:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{k=1}^{K} \delta_{a, j}\delta_{b,k}A_{j,k} = A_{a, b}$$

How to make Mathematica do that?

Try:

```
$Remove["Global*"]
$Assumptions = Element[a | b, Integers] && 1 <= a <= J && 1 <= b <= K; 
expr = Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, j]*KroneckerDelta[b, k]
           *A[j, k], {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}]
Simplify[expr]
```

Result:

```
Simplify can't simplify expr.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use DiscreteDelta instead of KroneckerDelta. With this substitution, the setup is:

```
$Assumptions = Element[a | b, Integers] && 1 <= a <= J && 1 <= b <= K;
expr = Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - j]*DiscreteDelta[b - k]*A[j, k], {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}]

A[Ceiling[a], Ceiling[b]]
```

Amazingly, it isn't even necessary to invoke Simplify, though I suppose it might in more complicated situations. To see that this substitution of DiscreteDelta for KroneckerDelta is correct, observe that

```
KroneckerDelta[a, j] == DiscreteDelta[a - j] // FullSimplify
True
```

Comment: No wonder one question here asked how to replace all `KroneckerDelta` with `DiscreteDelta`.

Comment: If a and j are equal, so that KroneckerProduct[a,j] is 1, then DiscreteDelta[a-j] is also 1. Similarly for a and j unequal, both KroneckerProduct[a,j] and DiscreteDelta[a-j] are zero. So they *are* the same with appropriate translation of the arguments.

Comment: I understand the trick now. Thanks.

Comment: Replace all KroneckerDelta by DiscreteDelta: `ReplaceDelta[expr_] = expr /. KroneckerDelta[a_, b_] -> DiscreteDelta[a - b];` This is so simple! Thanks!

Comment: 4 hours and Mathematica is still not done. This looks a bit like a dead-end.

Answer (score 7):

Why not work with symbolic tensors instead? For example, your sum can be represented as:

```
s = TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[
        IdentityMatrix[j],
        IdentityMatrix[k],
        A
    ],
    {{2, 5}, {4, 6}}
];
```

The built-in function [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) is not quite able to simplify this, but you can install my [`TensorSimplify`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159750/45431) paclet to enable simplification. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

Once installed, load the package with:

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

Finally, let's try `TensorSimplify` on your example:

```
TensorSimplify[s, Assumptions -> A ∈ Matrices[{j, k}]]
```

> A

Comment: I am not familiar with tensor sum/product yet. The expression is from derivative of matrix equation, which isn't in terms of tensor sum/product (similar to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186330/derivative-with-respect-to-any-element-of-a-matrix) For now, I manually simplify the expression, but I can make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Assume each summation is over all possible values of an index.

Assume the two indices of each Kronecker delta have the same domain.

Simplify Kronecker delta sum:

```
test = Sum[A[j, k, l]*KroneckerDelta[j, a]*KroneckerDelta[k, b]*
   B[j, k, l, m] + 
     A[j, k, m]*KroneckerDelta[l, c]*KroneckerDelta[j, a]*
   KroneckerDelta[k, b]*
       B[j, k, l, m], {j, 1, J}, {k, 1, K}, {l, 1, L}, {m, 1, L}]

f[exp_] := 
 exp /. {(x1_) + (x2__) :> f[x1] + f[Total[{x2}]], 
   Sum[(x1_) + (x2__), z__] :> f[Sum[x1, z]] + f[Sum[x2, z]], 
   Sum[c1___*(x1_ + x2__)*c2___, z__] :> 
    f[Sum[c1*c2*x1, z]] + f[Sum[c1*c2*x2, z]], (c__)*
     Sum[x1__, z__]*(c2___) :> c*c2*f[Sum[x1, z]], 
   Sum[Sum[x1__, z1__], z2__] :> f[Sum[x1, z1, z2]], 
   Sum[(c1___)*KroneckerDelta[r_, s_]*(c2___), z1__, {s_, 1, p_}, 
     z2___] :> f[Sum[c1*c2 /. s -> r, z1, z2]], 
   Sum[(c1___)*KroneckerDelta[r_, s_]*(c2___), z1___, {s_, 1, p_}, 
     z2__] :> f[Sum[c1*c2 /. s -> r, z1, z2]], 
   Sum[(c1___)*KroneckerDelta[r_, s_]*(c2___), {s_, 1, p_}] :> 
    f[c1*c2 /. s -> r]}

f[test]
```

Comment: Somehow this is faster than assumption + replace Kronecker by discrete + simplify.

Comment: Have problem when it try to expand the product of two summations with the same index. It doesn't know how to rename duplicated indices.